Did Lot have only 2 daughters?
I cannot interpret ancient Hebrew, and so this is a question about the translation of Genesis 19, and what fits most consistently with the original texts. There are 2 'clues' from the text in Genesis 19 that may suggest Lot had more than 2 daughters/children.

In verse 14, Lot went and spoke to his sons-in-law, 'who had married his daughters' and encouraged them to flee from the city, which seems to contrast his words to the crowd in verse 8, 'I have two daughters who have not known a man'.

In verse 15, the angels speak to Lot saying, 'Arise, take your wife and your two daughters who are here' [my emphasis], which suggests that there are some who are not there. It also draws to mind the charge to Rahab in Joshua 2, that her family would not be protected just because they were her family, but only if they were physically in her house (Joshua 2:17-18)


The problem I am facing is that translations aren't consistent. The more modern translations (NIV, AMP, ESV) translate verse 14 as men 'who were betrothed/promised to' Lot's daughters (although the NIV does have the alternative 'married to' as an editorial note), and the 'who are here' from the angels in verse 15 could just be identifying the fact that the sons-in-law didn't turn up.
I would appreciate someone who is able to unpack the original texts to provide some wisdom here, if it can be made clearer.
Thanks and God bless

It is quite clear from the more accurate translations (KJV and Young's Literal) that the sons in law had married but not consummated the marriages.
The reason for that may well be the result of the appalling wickedness that was prevalent in the town, and that was exampled when Lot had to remonstrate with the crowd and when the angels struck the crowd with blindness.
This shocking wickedness was the cause of the destruction of the city. Some translations appear to be attempting to mitigate the situation which is reported.
But the narrative makes no accusation of what cannot be evidenced. The narrative just states certain facts and we have to draw our own conclusions.

I'm really looking for guidance from the original texts as I know that there are difference opinions as to the accuracy of different translations, although I appreciate your response. I do wonder though whether that would be clear because the text also suggests that "all the men" came to Lot's house, although the way the text reads would suggest that all of them didn't include his sons in law
